# Where should we ask "Passage reading" based questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

You are given a passage then you will be given few questions based on the passage. You have to answer the questions based on the given passage.

---

**Example question:**

> Passage:
>
> I felt the wall of the tunnel shiver. The master alarm squealed
> through my earphones. Almost simultaneously, Jack yelled down to me
> that there was a warning light on. Fleeting but spectacular sights
> snapped into ans out of view, the snow, the shower of debris, the
> moon, looming close and big, the dazzling sunshine for once unfiltered
> by layers of air. The last twelve hours before re-entry were
> particular bone-chilling. During this period, I had to go up in to
> command module. Even after the fiery re-entry splashing down in 81o
> water in south pacific, we could still see our frosty breath inside
> the command module.
>
> Question:
>
> The word 'Command Module' used twice in the given passage indicates
> perhaps that it deals with
>
> A. an alarming journey
>
> B. a commanding situation
>
> C. a journey into outer space
>
> D. a frightful battle.
>
> Source: [IndiaBIX](https://www.indiabix.com/verbal-ability/comprehension/discussion-2098)

---

Edit: Sorry for being unclear at first. My question is which Stack Exchange site is apt to ask questions of above type when am getting some different option rather than given key/option with a suitable argument to support my claim?

Comment: What would your question be?

Comment: If you are asking us to answer the question that is posed _by_ the passage (i.e., what does 'Command Module' imply about the passage), there is no Stack Exchange site where this would be appropriate, as questions that amount to "do my homework for me" or "take this test for me" are strongly discourage if not explicitly off-topic.

Answer (score 10):

This question isn't suitable for the Stack Exchange network. It is not useful for anyone except for those people making the *exact same test* as you. The purpose of that test is not to see if one has sufficient skills to use the Internet to find solutions to their problems (though that *is* a very valuable skill); it's to judge whether someone is capable of finding the solution by themselves, through the use of comprehension or logic. Stack Exchange (or any other website) is not a replacement for this.

[Sometimes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/110021/11110), the process of getting to a solution is worth documenting, regardless of the source. For questions like this, it is not.

Answer (score 6):

If your question relates to *why* the answer is a given answer from a linguistic perspective  (for instance, "What specifically about the term 'command module' makes it clear that this was a space flight?  Couldn't it be, say, a military aircraft flight or similar?") this question could well be on-topic on [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

If you just want the question quoted in the passage answered, this question would not be on-topic anywhere on the Stack Exchange network, as questions copy-pasted from other sources that don't ask for additional, specific analysis are generally discouraged.

Make sure your question makes clear what *exactly* about the passage and question you're quoting that you want to know.  The quoted section from your question as-is would not be sufficient without additional information like the example in the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Yep, copied and pasted with typos and disagreement of number errors. Not great from an educational perspective.

Comment: I'd welcome any feedback on issues with this answer that merited it a downvote.  I'd be happy to correct any issues or remove it entirely if it's incorrect as a whole.

Comment: That's weird, I can't see anything this answer's not covered.